# When I normalize my X, it changes the curve

Tags: r, excel, sigmoid-curve

I am going between Excel and R for this understand the fitted lines of this experiment.  I have X and I have Y. When plotted it give me a curve that looks slightly sigmoidal, but I realize the X goes from 1 to 1000.

```
X   Y
1.00E+00    1.50E-09
2.00E+00    2.00E-09
6.00E+00    4.20E-09
1.00E+01    6.00E-09
1.30E+01    6.50E-09
1.70E+01    6.80E-09
2.80E+01    8.40E-09
5.00E+01    1.00E-08
1.00E+02    1.35E-08
2.00E+02    2.00E-08
4.00E+02    2.80E-08
6.00E+02    3.60E-08
8.00E+02    4.64E-08
1.00E+03    5.80E-08

datafile <-cbind(X, Y)

plot(datafile$Y~datafile$X)

datafile <-datafile%>%  
  mutate(y = (8e-17)*(X^3) - (1e-13)*(X^2) + 1e-10*X + 4e-09)%>%  #from excel
  mutate(Q_fitted =1.766e-08+6.375e-08*X-3.026e-09*X^2+5.657e-09*X^3) #from R

fit <-lm(Y~poly(X,3), datafile)
fitdata <-data.frame(datafile$X)
prediction = predict(fit,fitdata,se.fit=TRUE)
fitdata$fitted = prediction$fit
fitdata$ymin = fitdata$fitted - 1.96*prediction$se.fit
fitdata$ymax = fitdata$fitted + 1.96*prediction$se.fit

COR = cor.test(datafile$X,datafile$Y)[c("estimate","p.value")]
COR_text = paste(c("R=","p="),signif(as.numeric(COR,3),3),collapse=" ")


plot_ly(datafile, x=~V)%>%
  add_markers(x=~V, y=~y, name="Excel equation",,
              marker = list(size = 10,
                            color = 'rgba(255, 182, 193, .9)',
                            line = list(color = 'rgba(152, 0, 0, .8)',
                                        width = 1)))%>%
  add_markers(datafile$X, datafile$Y, marker=list( color="purple"), name="original")%>% 
  add_trace(x = ~X, y = fitted(fit), name="R fitted", mode="lines", type="scatter")%>%
  add_markers(fitdata$datafile.V, fitdata$fitted, line=list("green"), name="fitted points") %>%
  add_ribbons(data=fitdata, ymin = ~ ymin, ymax = ~ ymax,
              line=list(color="#F1F3F8E6"),fillcolor ="#F1F3F880" )
```

As you can see the values it returns start to fall away from the ideal curve especially at higher X-values.
So, I took the log10(X) in Excel, and it gives me a beautiful curve with a fitted line y= 2E-09e^(1.1411x) with and R-squared=0.98, worse than the original of 0.994
the polynomial is a close approximation but still falls out of the region of acceptability for our model.

So, I am wondering should I use a sigmoidal equation, and not polynomial or exponential? I am not as proficient in non-linear regression as linear so I am not sure what to do.

Comment: $\log_e(10) \approx 2.302585093$ so $e^{ 2.302585093 \log_{10}(X)} = 10^{\log_{10}(X)} =X$ up to rounding.  Have you mixed up $X$ and $Y$ and simply shown $X=X$?

Comment: Yes, you are right about that. LOL Be smarter than the tools you use. But how do I create the  exponential regression in R? All the ones I have seen are more for "decay" than "growth". I use those terms loosely because those are time dependent this is charge. So, how do I assign alpha, beta, and theta to this model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found out that none of the above would work, after talking to my co-worker, I was informed that the x was voltage and y was change. This wont work because y is not independent from x because Charge = Voltage * Capacitance.

Comment: If this is the last word on that you should know, that after 48 hours you can accept your own answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer